# Unable to correctly generate checksum

Tags: java, checksum

I am trying to calculate a simple checksum and then I'm doing a checksum test.

```
public void readfile()
{

    byte counter = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[68];     
    while(x.hasNextInt())
    {
        data[counter++] = (byte)x.nextInt();
        if(counter == 67)
            break;

    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 67; i++)
        sum += (data[i] & 0xFF);
    System.out.println((int)(sum & 0xFF)); //checksum

    //perform checksum test.
    data[counter] = (byte)(sum & 0xFF);
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 68; i++)
        sum += (data[i] & 0xFF);

    System.out.println((int)(sum & 0xFF)); //checksum test
}
```

I am reading the first 67 integer values of a file and saving them inside a byte array. All the integers are < 256. The variable 'x' is the file that I am reading. However, when I perform the checksum test, the value outputted isn't 0. I am not able to diagnose where I am computing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.
You get the first 67 characters, calculate a checksum, and then assume that those 67, plus the checksum, is 0. It is not. You're ADDING the checksum, not subtracting it.

So if the checksum is not 0 or 128, you end up with a value that is twice the checksum. Right?

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem!